# Can't find "Use .NET Standard" when creating a Xamarin.Forms project with Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am trying this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml?tabs=macos) as I want to create a simple Xamarin.Forms project to plugin to my other project. The parent tutorial is [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/light-up-mac-apps-with-xamarin-forms). In the parent tutorial it stated:

> You can see most of this code is boilerplate - and it's the only thing
> you really need to do in the MacOS project. All of your app's UI and
> business logic code can happily reside in the shared Xamarin.Forms
> project. Xamarin.Forms code in a shared project simply points to a
> start page with minimal XAML, like so:

It gives sample code. That was why I was trying to setup a project with Xamarin.Forms. But when creating this XAML project, in the tutorial is shows:

[image]

Yet in my Visual Studio for Mac all I see is:

[image]

It is missing the **Use .NET Standard** options. Ultimately I want to create a simply XAML form so I can use it with the other project. And I am wanting to run this GUI on MacOS.

---

### Update

If I go ahead a create a empty project then, and add it as a referenced project, I still don't know how to get my `appDelegate` file to fire up an instance of that xaml window:

[image]

Comment: I'd guess that tutorial has not been updated to match recent VS changes.  .NET Standard is not the default for new projects

Comment: @Jason So what do you do now if you want to make a simple Xamarin.Forms project suitable for use with my other project (if that makes sense!).

Comment: I disagree with @jason on that I think standard IS the standard. When you just proceed in this dialog and hit create the solution created does use a .net standard project for code sharing.

Comment: "suitable for use with my other project" - I have no idea what your other project is.  Is it compatible with .NET Standard?

Comment: @Jason See "parent tutorial" link above. That is the main tutorial.

Comment: The shared project option was removed from VS Mac, from what I remember, and the Blank Forms template now creates a .NET Standard project.

Comment: Yeah, had a look at the code. VS Mac 8.5 removed the option to create a Shared project here, to align with VS on Windows. It creates a .NET Standard project now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2019-mac-relnotes-v8.5#xamarin

Comment: @MattWard OK. But sadly I still feel left in the lurch here. I have this project and I add it as a project to the main one. But i still have no idea how to use the XAML file from that sub project in the main one. I am missing something.

Comment: Been a while since I tried a Xamarin.Mac macOS project. The macOS project should reference the same Xamarin.Forms NuGet package as the other projects, it would also need to reference the .NET Standard project. Then add the extra code to wire up the existing main page from the .NET Standard project.

Comment: @MattWard It is all new to me. I am used to WIndows.

Comment: your Mac project needs a reference to the GUI Library project.  This is basic project reference that applies to any .NET solution

Comment: @Jason I have done that as you can see in the last image. I added it as a reference.

Comment: that image does not show a reference between MacOS project and the GUI project.  It should be clearly listed in the References tree

Comment: double-click on References, select the "Projects" tab, and then select the GUI project

Comment: @Jason Thanks. I did not tick it even though it was listed as a project. Now I can add a reference with the using keyword and adjust the code. /it compiles although /I now get exception. But that is for another question if I can't solve it. Thanks.

Comment: You can open a new thread if you have another question:).